# Issue in printing column with gawk

Tags: awk, gawk

This is my data stored as `Exist_eutran_freqs.csv`:

```
120,1775
2984,1800
1942,2850
65,150
206,3050
8,1825
45,125
```

when I want to print them by below gawk command and switch the `col1` and `col2`, I'm getting below output!

#### Command:

```
gawk -F'[,]' '{print $2,$1}'  Exist_eutran_freqs.csv
```

#### Output:

```
 120
 2984
 1942
 65
 206
 825
 45
```

what is the solution for this?

Comment: Cannot reproduce, it works for me.  Your field separator is excessive though, you could just do `-F,` or `-F','`

Comment: I changed but there is no difference.gawk -F, '{print $2,$1}'  Exist_eutran_freqs.csv     
 120
 2984
 1942
 65
 206
 825
 45

Comment: Is your file a DOS text file?

Comment: No It's just simple *.csv file

Comment: Yeah I can reproduce on a file with CRLF line endings

Comment: Yes, confirmed. If converted to DOS text file format, I get that exact output. Please consider converting your data to Unix text using e.g. `dos2unix Exist_eutran_freqs.csv`.

Comment: I'm closing this as a duplicate of the question that Jesse_b linked to. Your issue is with the particular line-endings that DOS text files uses. The answers to that other question outlines ways to convert the file to a Unix text file.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks a lot, with your solution issue solved.  file originally has been generated by DOS.